# What can we say about the dimensionality of the irreducible representations of $SU(3)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

I've read about $SU(2)$ group in my physics course. The irreducible representations of $SU(2)$ are $(2j+1)$ dimensional where $j=0,1/2,1,3/2,...$

What can we say about the dimensionality of the irreducible representations of $SU(3)$?

Comment: The answer is given by [Weyl's dimension formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula), but you need a bit of Lie theory to make sense out of that. Anyway, the finite dimensional reps are parametrized by two integers, the numerator in that formula is a cubic polynomial in those two parameters, and the denominator is a constant. I'm  relatively sure somebody somewhere has expanded and posted that formula in the case of $SU(3)$.

Comment: The reason I don't know that answer by heart is that to an algebraist those two parameters are more natural objects of study than the dimension of the rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimensions of finite dimensional irreducible representations of $SU(3)$ are given by [Weyl's dimension formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula). The root system of $SU(3)$ is of type $A_2$, so the positive roots are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, the half-sum of positive roots it $\rho=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ where $\lambda_i$ are the fundamental dominant weights determined by duality: $(\lambda_i,\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

When we look at the irreducible representation $V(\lambda)$ with highest weight $\lambda=m_1\lambda_1+m_2\lambda_2$, $m_1,m_2$ non-negative integers, Weyl's formula gives
$$
\dim V(\lambda)=\frac{(\lambda+\rho,\alpha_1)(\lambda+\rho,\alpha_2)(\lambda+\rho,\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}{(\rho,\alpha_1)(\rho,\alpha_2)(\rho,\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}=\frac{(m_1+1)(m_2+1)(m_1+m_2+2)}{2}.
$$
So

- $V(\lambda_1)$ and $V(\lambda_2)$ are 3-dimensional. One is the defining rep, the other its dual. Depends on how you select the positive roots which is which.
- $V(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ is 8-dimensional. This is the adjoint representation.
- $V(2\lambda_1)$ and $V(2\lambda_2)$ are both 6-dimensional. They are the symmetric squares of the 3-dimensional reps.
- $V(3\lambda_1)$ and $V(3\lambda_2)$ are 10-dimensional. They are the symmetric third powers of the 3-dimensional reps, and IIRC played a role in the development of particle physics (as did the adjoint rep).
- In general $V(m_1\lambda_1+m_2\lambda_2)$ and $V(m_2\lambda_1+m_1\lambda_2)$ are each others duals.

Comment: You implicity use that $SU(3)$ is simply connected, so that all representations of the Lie algebra indeed exponentiate.

Comment: Correct @YCor. I forgot about that. Thanks for bringing it up! If we mod out the center of $SU(3)$, a cyclic group of order three consisting of scalar matrices, then we need to restrict $\lambda$ to come from the root lattice generated by $\alpha_1=2\lambda_1-\lambda_2$ and $\alpha_2=-\lambda_1+2\lambda_2$.